# Vue image src file path not working

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Im having a problem loading a image via file_path on vue if I used a hardcoded path its working. See sample code below

Javascript

```
function getRestaurantsbyId(id) {
    var restaurants = {
        "1" : {
            "name": "xxxx",
            "description": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "address": "xxxxxxxx",
            "contact_number": "rttttttttt"
            "cover_image": "images/clients/1/xxxxxx.jpeg"
        }
    };
    return restaurants[id];
}

var restaurant_info = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        info: getRestaurantsbyId(restaurant_id)
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<img src="{{ info.cover_image }}" class="respimg" alt="">
```

as per other solutions on the web I tried the follow below.

```
<img :src="{{ info.cover_image }}" class="respimg" alt=""> # Display my page as blank not sure why.

<img :src="images/clients/1/xxxxxx.jpeg" class="respimg" alt=""> # Working if value is hardcoded.
```

Any comments and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try calling the `getRestaurantsbyId` function in the `created` method.

```
function getRestaurantsbyId(id) {
    var restaurants = {
        "1" : {
            "name": "xxxx",
            "description": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "address": "xxxxxxxx",
            "contact_number": "rttttttttt"
            "cover_image": "images/clients/1/xxxxxx.jpeg"
        }
    };
    return restaurants[id];
}

var restaurant_info = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        info: {
          cover_image: null
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        this.info = getRestaurantsbyId(restaurant_id);
    }
})
```

And in your template, you don't need to add curly braces when binding to the src

```
<img :src="info.cover_image" class="respimg" alt="">
```